# iOS app crashes immediately after printing log [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialisation successful

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, frameworks, xcode9

I have created a project and using some third party framework I have imported them properly in app and trying to use them. However I am not getting any error during compile time. The app crashes at runtime printing the log
**"[DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful."**

I searched alot. However couldn't get any help.

Please find the screenshot for log.
[image]

Comment: crash log says there is no known method fmToArray declared on NSArray type object class. See where that method is getting called.

Comment: That is what i cant figure out till now i did not even use any array or such method in my view controller code.@TejaNandamuri